# Proper model formulation for nonlinear mixed effects model

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, nonlinear-regression

I have a question about how to properly write an equation to describe my model formulation, which is based on nonlinear mixed effects models.
My data consists of tree heights (*H*) and diameters (*D*) distributed on different plots (*plID*), which are random effects in nonlinear models. The nonlinear equation I use to predict *H* based on *D* is Curtis' 2-parameter growth curve:

**H(D)=bH+a(D/(1+D))^2**

where *a* and *b* are model parameters.
Now I want to insert the random effect (*plID*) into this equation and I am not sure how to write the equation correctly.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the model equation you have given does not make much sense, since it has $H$ on both sides! I found the paper [Modeling the height-diameter relationship of planted Pinus kesiya in Zambia](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378112719306188) which contains a list of theoretical models for the height-diameter relationship, and they give the Curtis model as
$$
   H= \beta_0 + \beta_1 \left(\frac{d}{1+d}\right)^{\beta_2}
$$ (you seem to have $\beta_2=2$).

Then to your question, how to formulate this as a nonlinear mixed model?

You want plots as random effects, but must decide for *what varies between plots*? First, a random intercept model would be, with $i$ index for trees, and $j$ for plots:
$$  \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
 \E H_{ij}= \beta_{0j} + \beta_1 \left(\frac{d_{ij}}{1+d_{ij}}\right)^{\beta_2}.
$$ If you also want random slopes, the model could be written
$$
  \E H_{ij}= \beta_{0j} + \beta_{1j} \left(\frac{d_{ij}}{1+d_{ij}}\right)^{\beta_2}.
$$